# ng serve freezes at 92%

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular9

I am trying to execute my angular application, but it freezes at 92%.

Here is the screen shot

[image]

I tried **npm cache clean** to check is it something with cache. Doesnt worked
ALso updated the typescript based on a suggestion which is also  not helped.

Im working in Angular 9, npm 6.14

Comment: does `ng build --watch` or `ng build --prod` give you any output?

Comment: `but it freezes at 92%.` ← How long did you wait before you gave up on the process?

Comment: I waited 1 hr and then terminated the session

Comment: @michal.jakubeczy Thanks . I just tried ng build --wait and it says an unhandled exception occured. illegal operation on a diractory. I didnt understand whats that mean or how to solve it

Comment: @SandeepThomas can you paste the error here, it will be the cause.

Comment: @michal.jakubeczy This is the error message I'm getting
An unhandled exception occurred: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory

Answer (score 2):

at the end I got a solution. Really wondering why the compiler behaves so weird where there is real bug in angular.json file.

The issue happened was at the **angular.json** file. There was an extra empty item in the scripts array which casued the trouble.

like this

```
"scripts": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js","node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js", ""]
```

Also what I believe is, if there is a path error as well, compiler trigger the same error.

Thanks all